# How to merge two Keras tensors ? (?, 4) and (?, 4) to (?, 4, 2)

Tags: python, merge, keras, tensor

After some calculation in Keras Model, I've got two tensors. Its shape is `(?, 4)`.
And I want to merge them into one new tensor.
For example. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 6, 7, 8]` to `[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]`.
How can I get it?

Comment: try `stack` ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stack function from tensorflow backend as the following code:

```
import keras.backend as K
...
z = K.stack([x,y],axis=-1)
```

Where shape of x, y is (?,4); Shape of z will be (?,4,2)